# Why does not match Center points with Object?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to track an object based on centre points and for detection, I used Cascade algorithm. I am using The centroid tracking algorithm from this page. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/

In this post-https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/. Authors used a deep neural network algorithm for detection and I want to use Cascade. but when I pass bounding box as Recs for detect centres, It just shows on the frame for each object one ID point, but it's not exactly in the centre of each object. In the below, I added a photo of my result.
Thank you very much

````
```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
body = fullbody_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
rects = []
for (i, (startX, startY, endX, endY)) in enumerate(body):
    if endY < 85:
    rects.append(body[i].astype('int'))
    pad_w, pad_h = int(0.15 * endX), int(0.05 * endY)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX + pad_w, startY - pad_h), (startX + endX - 
                  pad_w, startY + endY - pad_h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# here pass the rects to find centers
objects = ct.update(rects)
for (objectID, centeroid) in objects.items():
     text = "Id {}".format(objectID)
     cv2.putText(frame, text, (centeroid[0] - 10, centeroid[1] - 10), 
                 cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
     cv2.circle(frame, (centeroid[0], centeroid[1]), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf9BP.jpg)

Comment: What debugging have you tried?

Comment: fortunately, I found one line code which has been solved my problem. but I don't know how this code work. anybody can explain to.                               
"rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in body])"

Comment: That sounds like a different question, especially as you didn’t show that code in this question.

Comment: I found this code later and I put that code after " rects=[ ] " and then my problem solved. but I don't know what does it mean.